# How do I initialise this variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, initialization, statements

```
package testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){


    String input; 
    String userInput; 
    String Joshua; 

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (input != Joshua){
            System.out.println("You aren't Joshua. Leave.");
        }  
    }

}
```

//I am receiving the error in the "if" statement. What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to initialise "Joshua"?

Comment: You need to initialize the attribute `Joshua`(e.g. `String Joshua = "Joshua";`). Also, [never compare Strings with `==` or `!=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

```
String joshua = "Joshua";
```

You just named your variable, but did not assign any value.

Additionally, use the [equals(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method to compare strings! The `==` operator only checks, whether the two variables share the same location in the memory, the `equals()` method checks, if the content is equal.

```
if(joshua.equals(input))
{
// just do it
}
```

Comment: I'm new to programming so the equals(Object obj) method is nigh inscrutable. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
if (input.equals("Joshua") {
    //Master stuff...
} else {
    //You are not Joshua!
}
```

Okay, so

1: You never defined a value for the string `Joshua`.

2: You don't even need a variable for that. Just do `"Joshua"` in the `if statement`.

EDIT: Okay, if you really wanted to use a variable for that, you initialize it by doing:

`String Joshua = "Joshua";`

And when it comes to strings, use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `==` or `=!` to compare strings!

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Now my code isn't even acknowledging my if statement at all. There is no error done by the compiler:

Comment: System.out.println("What is your name?");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();    
        
        if (input == Joshua){
            System.out.println("Hello, master. How are you feeling today?");
        
            if (input != Joshua){
            System.out.println("You aren't Joshua. Try again.");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: I updated the code. Check it, and don't forget to do initialize the variable as I showed you if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In java instance variables (**defined in class**) get their default values.

You have initialize to Local variables (**defined in methods**). Because they don't have any default value.

1. You can use `String Joshua = null;` or `String Joshua = "some value here";` to initialize `Joshua` variable and then use.
2. You can make your variable an instance (**define `Joshua` in class**) and make it `static` to use directly in your `static` method `main`.

One more thing, you are not following **Java naming convention** for your `Joshua` variable. It should be `joshua`.

Hope this help **:)**